# Invoking two separate parsers from a C program

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

Say that the names of the parsers are parser_1 and parser_2.

parser_1:

> Bison file = parser_1.y
>
> Flex file  = parser_1.l

After Compiling with gcc I get my paser in the following two files:

> parser_1.tab.c and parser_1.lex.yy.c

Similary my parser_2 consitst of:

> parser_2.tab.c and parser_2.lex.yy.c

I am trying to compile both the parsers together because me program needs both the parsers. **I cannot replace the two parsers by one parser** because the following two reasons. The grammars are completely different and the parsers are to be invoked at entirely different statges of my program.

```
gcc parser_1.tab.c parser_1.lex.yy.c \
    parser_2.tab.c parser_2.lex.yy.c \
    my_program.c -lfl
```

It gives me error that some functions like `yylex ()`, `yyparse ()` etc. have been defined multiple times, which is understandable.

**My Question:**
   Is there some method by which I can have the two parsers in my program?
Or please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke use multiple parsers from a C program there are two methods:

1. Use multiple start symbols, if grammars are closely related. 
      For details see
   http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Multiple-start_002dsymbols.html
2. Change the prefix `yy` for parser(s). This would remove all the name conflicts. A new prefix can be specified using the option `-Dapi.prefix={prefix}`.

   You will need to modify the prefixes of the lexical analyser also, if you are using a separte lexical analyser. This can be achieved by using the `--prefix=PREFIX` flag.

For details about renaming in Bison see: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Multiple-Parsers.html

For details about renaming in Flex see: http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/#Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options

In flex you will need to specify `%option noyywrap` as the very first line of the `.l` file. For details see: http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-yywrap_0028_0029